# Command to show all the local git repo's of the remote repo

Tags: git

If I cloned remote repo in many local folders on my PCs, is there a command to show me all
of those path's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the cloned repositories do not know of each other, and the remote repository does not know who cloned it.

Perhaps you would like to use [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) instead of having multiple clones. Then it would be possible to list all the worktrees.